# Attached PDF to email in Swift, but the PDF is not decoded

Tags: swift, pdf

I have succcessfully attached a PDF document to an email as follows.

```
  @IBAction func emailScript(_ sender: Any) {

    print ("Now the value of pdfPath is \(SelectedPDF)")
    let pdfURL = URL(string:SelectedPDF)

    print ("The value of pdfURL is \(pdfURL)")

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.setMessageBody("<p>You're so awesome!</p>", isHTML: true)
        mail.setToRecipients(["Enter one or more emails here"])

        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self  //  Make sure to set this property to self, so that the controller can be dismissed!

        //Set the subject
        mail.setSubject("email with document pdf")


            if let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: pdfURL!) {
                print ("File data loaded.")
                print (fileData)
                mail.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "GST")
            }

            present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    else {

        print ("Error")
    }

}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

I am sure that the fileData is not nil. The data stream shows up in the console. The attachment shows up as a PDF.  But when I send the email from my app, the PDF is not readable. In my iPad, I get a gray screen with the title bar.  On my Mac, I get an error saying that the PDF was not decoded.

The PDF is from my Dropbox and its URL comes from a Parse server app.

The pdf link, which works in a browser, is https://www.dropbox.com/s/rt28egrkyc7uhc7/GSTPurim5777.pdf?dl=0

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

Eli

Comment: You are attaching a Data file, not a PDF file, to your message.

Comment: @ElTomato That's the only way to attach a file. Most likely the problem is that the URL doesn't actually result in a PDF file.

Comment: This is the URL of the PDF.  It works in a browser.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/rt28egrkyc7uhc7/GSTPurim5777.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  Dropbox URLs, at least for PDFs if not everything, include a dl=0 tag to indicate downloading permission. In order to send a PDF through an app, you have to change the dl=0 to dl=1.  Then everything works as it should.

So there would be no change to the code above.  The change is in my Parse browser where I list my files.

Eli